# Redshift: Change name of table on a daily basis

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to run a script on a daily basis, creating a new table every time to script runs.

I want my code to behave like the below:

```
CREATE TABLE adhoc.CURRENT_DATE AS 
    SELECT
```

How can I use a function to create a table that has the current date as the table name?

Comment: Have you considered instead just adding a Date column to your table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to write to dynamically created table in Redshift procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713329/how-to-write-to-dynamically-created-table-in-redshift-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

A Procedure which has the following content:

```
> Variable: Assign formatted sysdate to it 
> Prepare dynamic SQL: Keep everything static and your table name dynamic by using the above variable
> Execute: the dynamic query.
```

Schedule the procedure in a script.

You can refer my other answer for dynamic sql related syntax :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60724973/11739568